# some songs removed from my iTunes libary not always automatically removing from iPhone when using Match

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music, itunes-match

When I decide I no longer like one or more songs from my iTunes library I remove it in iTunes (and not just the download).

they then disappear out of my iTunes library and computer. All as expected

Then i go to my iPhone and **Often i will still find some of these removed songs on my phone.**

Not all but some songs never disappear slowly filling up my iPhone. this happens to songs that had been downloaded to the iphone but also to songs that remained in the cloud while they are long gone from my computer and iTunes.

(I use iOS 9.3.1 on an iphone 5 64gb and iTunes 12.3.3.17 on win 10 64bit)

Comment: Can you please restate your question?  I can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i just erased all data on my iPhone and restored it through iCloud. The songs that had been removed long ago finally left my phone. I suppose this is a solution but i really hope i wont have to do this too often.